# Can I create an application using SlimDX relying on the DirectX DLLs already bundled with Vista/Win7?

Tags: .net, deployment, directx, slimdx

I'm working on a .NET application that requires the use of accelerated graphics, currently DirectX 9.0c. The software is quite graphics intensive and must, in addition, be launchable from a CD or by ClickOnce without the user requiring administrator's permissions.

I currently use SlimDX, which works great featurewise, but the users are getting rather annoyed by having to install the DirectX redistributable. Especially since this does require elevated permissions. It is rather hard to explain to them why the version of DirectX already bundled with their OS is not sufficient. After all - DirectX 9.0c has been around since 2004, and I'm not using any new fancy features.

The ability to deliver an application that "just works" in Vista or Windows 7, without any particular additional prerequisites would be a huge advantage.

Therefore: Is there any way I can build an application using DirectX 9.0c based on SlimDX, that relies only on the libraries provided in the standard Windows Vista/Win7 installation? That is - without requiring the additional DirectX redistributable to be installed?

If not - is there any other managed (and preferably not abandoned) DirectX wrapper that can serve this purpose?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think SlimDX can't run wihout the DirectX redistributable, but it may be possible to bundle DirectX DLL directly into your assembly instead of installing them to GAC with the redistribuable pack. I haven't test this possibility by myself but it may be complex to load the right DirectX DLL in a generic way if you want this to work for x86 and x64 platforms.

I don't know about another DirectX Wrapper, but SlimDX seem to be the only one to run on x64 platforms.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That might be an option, and as far as I know it should be possible from a technical point of view. However, I have avoided it as I don't think that the license agreement of the DirectX Redistributable allows it. At least that is my interpretation of it, and my colleague has contacted Microsoft to try to get a straight answer from them. I will update the post when we know.